# Mailkit. How exclude attachment body from log

Tags: logging, settings, mailkit, mimekit

```
 using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))){
// Reading email with attacments}
```

How not include body attachement files while reading mails. How specify param for ProtocolLogger? Files may be vary large, and the log becomes unreadable and huge.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such parameter. You'll have to implement your own protocol logger that filters out the attachment data by somehow determining that some content is an attachment or not.

Personally, I think it's too difficult to bother.